# Is it possible to get the console (like in R studio) for google colab?

Tags: console, rstudio, google-colaboratory

I'm fairly new to programming, but the console in R studio was super helpful. I am now working on a project in google colab, which does not have a console, and I am suffering greatly.

Comment: Hi there, what sort of problems are you experiencing? Is it menus? Windows? Syntax highlighting?

Comment: there's not a problem per se. it's more just an issue of convenience. I'm using google colab and there's no console built into the GUI. they have 'scratch cells' but they're actually not much better

Answer (score 0):

I found it!! It's under Insert > Scratch code cell.